# Cannot find file "...\\r" when using os.path.join and trying to open file in read mode

Tags: python

In my current working directory, where I run my Python script, I have multiple subdirectories which all contain the file 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv'. I want to create a pandas dataframe of these files.

When I run my script, I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\KLIF\\Documents\\Linda\\genes.faa.genespercontig.csv\\r'
```

My script is as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv', 'r')) as f1:
        df1 = pd.read_csv('f1', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"]) 
        print(df1)
```

I am sure that the file is in the subdirectories, but why can Python not find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless "r" is a file within a directory called "genes.faa.genespercontig.csv", simple syntax error.  Your parentheses need adjusting slightly:

```
...
with open(os.path.join(root, 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv'), 'r') as f1:
...
```

Additionally, given that you say the file is contained within subdirectories, you probably need to loop over the subdirectories within the `dirs` variable returned by the `os.walk` function.  I notice that you use the string `'f1'` to pass to `pd.read_csv` but presumably you want the open file object.  Something like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for subdir in dirs:
        with open(os.path.join(root,subdir,'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv'),'r') as f1:
            df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"])
            print(df1)
```

To only attempt to open a file which actually exists, use:

```
...
filepath = os.path.join(root,subdir,'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv')
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
...
```

Comment: I adjust it, but it still gives the error that it does not find the files

Comment: @Gravel Added more detail.  I do not know your directory structure so is untested but have based it on the detail provided in your question

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks a lot! If I need it; can you advise me what to do, if I have a subdirectory that not contain this file? Because when I loop over the subdirectories, and the script can not find the file in a subdirectory, it will stop, and I want that it continues than with the next subdirectory.

Comment: @Gravel Added code so that you only attempt to open a file if it exists